# How to use the Spacebar for changing color in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a question about JS
i just want when i write for example Own(the 'Own' word is in the array) in the input feild and then i press spacebar the color of Own word in head gets green and when i write for example
'false' the color of the Own word in the head gets red
and i want this for the rest of them i Hope you Guys Find out what i'm saying
thanks..

```js
var seconds = 60;
var timer;
function myFunction() {
  if(seconds < 60) {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
  }
     if (seconds >0 ) {
         seconds--;
     } else {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }
}
document.getElementById("No1").onkeypress = function() {
  if(!timer) {
    timer = window.setInterval(function() {
      myFunction();
    }, 1000);
  }
} 

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="1:00";

var text = ["Own","food","need","turn","you"]
var i;
document.getElementById('Text').innerHTML +='';
for(i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    document.getElementById('Text').innerHTML += text[i]+" ";
}

const words = [];

const memorizer = (ev) => {
  const inp = ev.target;
  const val = inp.value.trim();
    
  if(ev.key === ' ') {
    const valSpl = val.split(' ');
    words.push(valSpl[0]);
    inp.value = valSpl[1] || ''; 
  }

  if(ev.key === ' ' && val === '' ) {
    inp.value = words.length ? words.pop() : '';
  }

  console.clear();console.log(words);
}

document.querySelector('#No1').addEventListener('keyup', memorizer);
```

```html
<html>

<body style="background-color: teal !important;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="col" class="col-12 font-weight-bold" style="background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;">
        <span id="Text"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <input id="No1" type="text" class="bg-white form-control" style="width: 80% !important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;">
        <div id="timer" style=" background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    width: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/index-1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_, _"**Describe the problem.** "How should I fix this?" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your "Text" span to a div container to put multiple span text in html file
2. In js file, use createElement("span") to put each text and append span to div container
3. when press whitespace, compare last element in words array with text array

Here is the code:

```js
var seconds = 60;
var timer;
function myFunction() {
  if (seconds < 60) {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
  }
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds--;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
document.getElementById("No1").onkeypress = function () {
  if (!timer) {
    timer = window.setInterval(function () {
      myFunction();
    }, 1000);
  }
};

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "1:00";

// create span to put text in Text div
var text = ["Own", "food", "need", "turn", "you"];
var i;
var textNode = document.getElementById("Text");
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement("span");
  s.id = text[i];
  s.innerHTML = text[i] + " ";
  textNode.appendChild(s);
}

const words = [];

const memorizer = (ev) => {
  const inp = ev.target;
  const val = inp.value.trim();

  if (ev.key === " ") {
    const valSpl = val.split(" ");
    words.push(valSpl[0]);
    inp.value = valSpl[1] || "";

    // compare the word is correct or not, and change color
    if (words[words.length - 1] === text[words.length - 1]) {
      document.getElementById(text[words.length - 1]).style.color = "green";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(text[words.length - 1]).style.color = "red";
    }
  }

  if (ev.key === " " && val === "") {
    inp.value = words.length ? words.pop() : "";
  }

  console.clear();
  console.log(words);
};

document.querySelector("#No1").addEventListener("keyup", memorizer);
```

```html
<html>
  <body style="background-color: teal !important">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div
          id="col"
          class="col-12 font-weight-bold"
          style="
            background-color: white;
            font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 30px;
          "
        >
          <!-- use Text div as a container to put text span -->
          <div id="Text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <input
            id="No1"
            type="text"
            class="bg-white form-control"
            style="
              width: 80% !important;
              display: inline-block;
              margin-top: 20px;
            "
          />
          <div
            id="timer"
            style="
              background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
              width: 60px;
              display: inline-block;
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 20px;
              color: white;
            "
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index-1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer was great and helpfull can you help me with something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917708/how-get-the-selected-date-in-datepicker-and-convert-it-into-another-input-feild im stuck in it please if you know the answer help me

Comment: ok! I'll check it later~

Comment: Thanks but i fidured it out thank you so much 